# If clojure is compiled to byte-code, why is there java source for clojure?

Tags: clojure

I feel like this is a noob question, but if clojure is compiled to byte code then why is there [java source](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/tree/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang) for the clojure lang?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some axioms:

- Clojure code that one writes in Clojure is compiled to bytecode.
- Java code that one writes in Java is also compiled to bytecode.
- Some core parts of Clojure is written in Java.

Comment: Now i'm embarrassed by this question I asked

Comment: @Thomas happens to everyone at times :)